How can i return JavaScript code instead of printing it in PHP?
    public function script(): string
    {
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                const foo = {
                    widgetcode: '<?= $this->widget_code() ?>',
                }
            </script>
            <?php
    }

This code works effectively, but as I'm moving a codebase to stricter standards (and I'm unfamiliar with php), how do I cast this return to a string?  What is incorrect with this syntax?  I've checked the php docs, but they are more focused on HEREDOC or NOWDOC, and this scripted code better lends itself to a non-php block with scriptlets like <?=.
How do I return this "script()" as a string?

This function does not return a string, the HTML code is printed.

I think you misunderstood how PHP returns code. When you call your function, your code is printed, but not returned.
To improve the readability of your code and to improve your PHP skills a bit, I split the original function into two separate. The script() function now retrieves the widget code, while the generateScript() function generates the JavaScript code.
The difference between RETURNING and PRINTING:

Printing: When you print the JavaScript code using echo or directly within the PHP tags (like you did with ?> and <?php). The output is sent directly to the browser - this means the JS code is immediately included in the HTML response that was sent to the client.

Returning: When you return the JS code as a string, the output is not immediately sent to the browser. Instead, it is returned to the caller of the function, which allows you to manipulate (or use the string further) before sending it to the browser.


I also used the HEREDOC syntax to make the JavaScript code more readable and maintainable by using multi-lines without the need for concatenation or escaping quotes.
public function script(): string
{
    $widgetCode = $this->widget_code();
    return $this->generateScript($widgetCode);
}

private function generateScript(string $widgetCode): string
{
    return <<<SCRIPT
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const foo = {
            widgetcode: '{$widgetCode}',
        }
    </script>
    SCRIPT;
}


I guess multiple interpolations, including fn calls are simply better declared up-front, then templated with HEREDOC syntax?  The HEREDOC fn call syntax looks convoluted.

Thank you, it was originally just printing, and now that I'm adding tests - that makes the difference.

The other answer is way cleaner, despite it uselessly declares variable $string. Passing properties of $this as argument is not required, unless having multiple widget codes.

@MartinZeitler Separating logic improves readability and maintainability. It also prepares the code for future changes, like handling multiple widget codes. This approach follows best practices for clean and modular code - my intention was that he can understand PHP a little bit better.

@MartinZeitler perhaps, but nothing is actually better from an authoring perspective than using the echo version of the non-php block.  Syntax coloring in vscode disappears with both methods.  But, that's just nice to have...
I also happen to have $ variables in the js script.  So, it get's worse in both, I need to escape them.
Thank you (both) though for the quick guidance

It should be like this
public function script(): string {

    $string = "
      <script type='text/javascript'>
        const foo = {
          widgetcode: ".$this->widget_code().",
        }
      </script>";
    return $string;
}

